# JQuery Toggle Display with less code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and learning this myself. I want to toggle my display using the least amount of code. My code currently works but I'm sure there is a better way. Cheers.

```
    <div id="container">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlHeader">
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="radOne" GroupName="myRadGroup" Text="One"      value="1" onclick="ToggleMyDisplay();" />
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="radTwo" GroupName="myRadGroup" Text="Two" value="2" onclick="ToggleMyDisplay();" />
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="radThree" GroupName="myRadGroup" Text="Three"  value="3" onclick="ToggleMyDisplay();" />
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="radFour" GroupName="myRadGroup" Text="Four"  value="4" onclick="ToggleMyDisplay();" />

    <div>
        <label for="ddlOne" id="lblOne">DDL One:</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOne" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlOne" Style="display: none;"> 
    <div>   
        <label for="ddlTwo">To:</label>            
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTwo" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>       
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTwo" Style="display: none;">
    <div>
        <label for="txtMyText">My Text:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>            
    </div>
</asp:Panel>


<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlThree" CssClass="fieldsLarge" Visible="true">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" style="width: 775px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>                    
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Here is the JQuery I have at the moment

```
    function ToggleMyDisplay() {

    if ($("#radOne").attr("checked") !== "undefined" && $("#radOne").attr("checked") === "checked") {
        MyLabel.text('First Radio Selected:');
        $("#pnlOne").hide();
        $("#pnlTwo").hide();
        $("#btnContinue").hide();
        $("#btnExit").hide();
        $("#btnSave").show();

    }

    else if ($("#radTwo").attr("checked") !== "undefined" && $("#radTwo").attr("checked") === "checked") {
        MyLabel.text('Second Radio Selected:');
        $("#pnlOne").hide();
        $("#pnlTwo").hide();
        $("#btnContinue").hide();
        $("#btnExit").hide();
        $("#btnSave").show();

    }

    else if ($("#radThree").attr("checked") !== "undefined" && $("#radThree").attr("checked") === "checked") {
        MyLabel.text('Third Radio Selected:');
        $("#pnlOne").show();
        $("#pnlTwo").show();
        $("#btnContinue").show();
        $("#btnExit").hide();
        $("#btnSave").show();

    }

    else if ($("#radFour").attr("checked") !== "undefined" && $("#radFour").attr("checked") === "checked") {
        MyLabel.text('F:');
        $("#pnlOne").show();
        $("#pnlTwo").show();
        $("#btnContinue").show();
        $("#btnExit").hide();
        $("#btnSave").show();     
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `data-*` attribute available with html5:

http://jsfiddle.net/eH5ru/1/

For purpose of the example, I used normal html elements, *not* ASP.NET controls. But the concept still applies.

I added a `data-show` attribute that contains a jquery selector, in this instance, its a class name, with this you can determine which elements to hide and which to show.

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        var showSelector = $(this).data('show');
        $('.display-part').hide();
        $(showSelector).show();
    }
});
```

This would make it easier to add/remove panels in the future.

Comment: Edited to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First idea: uses html class and function toggle for all elements which will change instead of uses id on few elements:

Exemple:

```
$("#pnlOne").show();
$("#pnlTwo").show();
$("#btnContinue").show();
$("#btnExit").hide();
$("#btnSave").show();
```

Becomes:

```
$(".elementChanged").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple selector:

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Some things worth considering. You are using ASP.Net controls and then accessing them with javascript with the id. For example the panels will render to html div-element when ASP.Net has rendered the page. The ID-property of the ASP.Net-control will not always be rendered directly as the div-elements id-attribute in html. So if your page was any more complex, your code would not work. If you don't need to access the panel on server side code, simply replace it with div in the first place:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTwo" Style="display: none;">
</asp:Panel>

->

<div id="pnlTwo" style='display: none;'>
</div>
```

If you do need to access these controls on server side, one thing you could do is use the [clientIdMode-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and set it to static. Or you could use css-classes to find the proper div from the html:

```
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTwo" CssClass="myClass">
    </asp:Panel>
```

Renders as

```
<div id="pnlTwo" class="myClass">
</div>
```

and you could find it with the class

```
$(".MyClass")...
```

Also you should use the [prop-function](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to check if radiobutton or checkbox is checked:

```
if ($("#myCheckbox").prop("checked") === true) {
}
```

Also a tip: if you want to do same thing to many elements, you can use the or-selector:

```
$("#pnlOne, #pnlTwo, #btnContinue, #btnExit").hide();
```

Or if all the elements have same parent element, you could hide the parent, hence hiding all the children.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If the javascript is rendered on the asp.net page, you could access `pnlTwo` with $('#<%= pnlTwo.ClientID%>')... as well :)